# How is scheduling handled in C++17 STL parallel algorithms?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, stl, c++17

Is there a standard scheduler specification for the C++17 STL parallel algorithms or is it entirely implementation dependant? The serial algorithms have complexity guarantees but the scheduler implementation is critical for performance with non uniform task loads, does the specification address this? It seems like it would be hard to guarantee cross-platform performance without a standardized scheduler.

Comment: The scheduler and more generally task-pools where to dispatch these jobs are not in C++17, so there are lots of limitations in these algorithms at this stage (IMHO).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell from [the wording](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel), such details are completely within the domain of implementation specification, as one would expect. The standard generally makes no effort to guarantee absolute performance of any kind, only complexity requirements, as you're seeing in this case.

Ultimately, though your source code can now take advantage of parallelism while being completely standard-defined, the actual practical outcome of running your program is up to your implementation, and I think that still makes sense. The goal of standardising features is not cross-platform performance, but portable *code* that can be proven correct in a vacuum.

I'd expect your toolchain to give further information on how this sort of thing works, and that may even influence your choice of toolchain! But it does make sense for them to have freedom in that regard, as they do in other areas. After all, there is a multitude of target platforms out there (theoretically infinite), all with their own potential and quirks.

It could be that a future standard emplaces further constraints on scheduling in order to kick implementers up the backside a little, but personally I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't really follow C++ developments nowadays. Peer review encouraged more than usual here.

Comment: I see what you are saying but without any cross-platform standards for scheduling it seems a bit useless for high performance computing.

Comment: @atb how do you propose describing a scheduler suitable for *all* implementations?

Comment: @cal I guess you would need some description of the load balancing algorithm used, or some way to specify it.

Comment: @cal, on further thought, I guess the execution policy would need to have more options for various types of parallel execution?

Comment: @atb I don't see why it's "useless". Again, ensuring cross-platform standards for _performance_ is not and has never been the standard's purview. That's down to the implementation for the specific technology that you're using. Not really seeing a problem here tbh.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, fair enough, not useless. but the standard does already specify complexity requirements for algorithms and many other performance related features so I disagree that it's only focus is correctness. the issues is that depending on the how the tasks are managed you may need to write an algorithm differently, so there is a direct connection between the user code and the scheduler type in high performance computing. whether you think the standard should address that dependancy or not is just a matter of opinion I guess.

Comment: hopefully most vendors will use tbb on the back end and it will be very useful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling for C++17 STL algorithms is implementation-defined.
Moreover, C++17 doesn't guarantee parallel execution. It just allows parallelism.

> The class execution::parallel_policy is an execution policy type used
>   as a unique type to disambiguate parallel algorithm overloading and
>   indicate that a parallel algorithm’s execution **may be parallelized**